# In Python All Fundamental Datatypes Are Immutable Why In String Replace() Function Works?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string

As we all know that All fundamental datatypes in python are immutable and we can't change anything in them,

If I try to replace something in fundamental data types I will definitely get an error. Take an example from this;

#TRYING TO REPLACE AN INTEGER FROM A VARIABLE.

```
num=123456789

1=78

print(num)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
File "D:\myPractice.py\sideRun.py", line 2
    1=78

    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal
```

If fundamental data types are immutable, then why is the string has replace() inbuilt function.

```
**#REPLACING A OLD STRING WITH A NEW STRING**

s="Jimmy is a student of CS and Jimmy is a boy "

print(id(s))

print(s.replace("CS","SE"))

print(id(s))
```

In this, both of print() statements that have ID argument are giving the same output that is the same address.

```
**MY QUESTIONS ARE**
```

1. If the string data type is immutable then why it has 'replace()' function?
2. If a new object is created due to 'replace()' function then why new and old string has the same ID?

Comment: `s.replace("CS","SE")` did not mutate `s`.

Comment: try your reasoning with `s = s.replace("CS","SE")` about `str.replace` `This method returns a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new`

Comment: @Deepak Kumar I think you are at something. You may open a bug for the python developers.

Comment: @FuryFart This is not a bug. This is just not fully comprehending what the functions/methods are explicitly documented to do.

Comment: @Deepak Kumar Please consider to [edit] your question to remove the obvious blunders of the example: ``print(s)`` *after* doing the replacement or assign the result of ``s.replace`` to ``s`` or another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.replace(...)` returns a modified copy of the given string. This method doesn't mutate your "s" variable.

```
s = "Jimmy is a student of CS and Jimmy is a boy "
s1 = s.replace("CS","SE")
print(id(s))
print(id(s1))

# your script did nothing but printed ids
# in this case s1 contains modified copy of string "s"
# script will print different ids
```